spin density plot for bilayer CrI3
I plotted the spin density plot for bilayer crI3 using VASPKIT and VESTA. My plot is completely different from what is reported in the literature. In the attached figure, the above one is reported in the paper and the below one I am getting. After optimization of bilayer CrI3, I performed SCF calculations and generated the spin density data using VASPKIT. Spin density distribution in the interlayer region is more important to get, as shown by the green arrow. I am not getting what worng I am doing.
